# Open video from gallery and Intent VideoView to new activity

Tags: android, video, android-intent, android-videoview, android-video-player

I want make video player app that launch from gallery and play the video to 'new activity'. the problem is, i already browse the video at the gallery. the video are playing at the 'main activity' not play at the 'new activity'. please help.

MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button button1;
VideoView videoView;
private static final int SELECT_VIDEO = 1;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    videoView=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("video/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"), SELECT_VIDEO);

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;

    if (requestCode == SELECT_VIDEO) {
        Uri mVideoURI = data.getData();
        videoView.setVideoURI(mVideoURI);

        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

        videoView.start();

        }
    }
}
```

what coding should i put in my 'new activity.java'?
and i also want to put 4 video in same activity. what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

put the intent in NewActivity not in MainActivity